# Build pandas data frame from list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wonder if there is an easy way for the obvious task to generate a pandas DataFrame from a list of numpy arrays, where the columns are the arrays. The default behavior seems to let the arrays be the rows, which I totally don't understand why. Here is a quick example:

```
names = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
data = [np.arange(10) for _ in names]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=names)
```

This gives an error, indicating pandas expects 10 columns.

If I do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I get a DataFrame with 10 columns and 3 rows.

Given that it is generally much more difficult to append rows than columns to a DataFrame I wonder about this behavior, e.g. let's say I quickly want to put a 4th data-array into the DataFrame I want the data to be organized in columns to do

```
df['data4'] = new_array
```

How can I quickly build the DataFrame I want?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @MaxGhenis pointed out in the comments, `from_items` is [deprecated as of version 0.23](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html). The link suggests to use `from_dict` instead, so the old answer can be modified to:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(names, data)))
```

--------------------------------------------------OLD ANSWER-------------------------------------------------------------

I would use [`.from_items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(names, data))
```

which gives

```
  data1  data2  data3
0      0      0      0
1      1      1      1
2      2      2      2
3      3      3      3
4      4      4      4
5      5      5      5
6      6      6      6
7      7      7      7
8      8      8      8
9      9      9      9
```

That should also be faster than transposing:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(names, data))
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 281 µs per loop

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(data, index=names).T
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 730 µs per loop

Adding a fourth column is then also fairly simple:

```
df['data4'] = range(1, 11)
```

which gives

```
  data1  data2  data3  data4
0      0      0      0      1
1      1      1      1      2
2      2      2      2      3
3      3      3      3      4
4      4      4      4      5
5      5      5      5      6
6      6      6      6      7
7      7      7      7      8
8      8      8      8      9
9      9      9      9     10
```

As mentioned by @jezrael in the comments, a third option would be (*beware: order not guaranteed*)

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(names, data)), columns=names)
```

Timing:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(names, data)))
```

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 281 µs per loop

Comment: Nice, alternative can be `pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(names, data)), columns=names)`

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks, I added this version as well. The `columns=names` part is not even required; then it is as fast as the `from_items` version.

Comment: Yes, but there is problem it is `dict` - order is not guaranteed, so need specify it. Try change `data1` to `data7` for difference ;)

Comment: @jezrael, good point :) Then I'll stick to the `from_items` version.

Comment: `from_items` is deprecated: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_items.html

Comment: @MaxGhenis: Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't work with numpy arrays: `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to solve your problem, but the easiest way seems to be `df.T` (`T` being shorthand for [`pandas.DataFrame.transpose`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=names)
>>> df
       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
data1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
data2  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
data3  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

>>> df.T 
   data1  data2  data3
0      0      0      0
1      1      1      1
2      2      2      2
3      3      3      3
4      4      4      4
5      5      5      5
6      6      6      6
7      7      7      7
8      8      8      8
9      9      9      9
```

Comment: So I initially declare my data-names as indexes, and then transpose..I see thx! Still, I don't understand the logic behind the default behavior.

Comment: Yep, that's one way to do it. I'm surprised at the `AssertionError` raised by the default behavior, too.

Answer (score 3):

`from_items` is now deprecated. Use `from_dict` instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'data1': np.arange(10),
  'data2': np.arange(10),
  'data3': np.arange(10)
})
```

This returns:

```
    data1   data2   data3
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9
```